# Footnote moves up by one \par

Tags: spacing, footnotes

What is the problem with this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{footdir@label}
\newtoks\footdir@toks
\newcommand*{\footdir@temp}[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \let#1#2%
    \renewcommand{#2}[1]{%
      \footdir@toks{##1}%
      \footdir@toks\expandafter{%
        \the\expandafter\footdir@toks
        \expandafter
        \zref@labelbyprops\expandafter{\thefootdir@label}{abspage}%
      }%
      \expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\footdir@toks}%
    }%
  }%
}

\footdir@temp\footdir@ORG@footnotetext\@footnotetext{L}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Refer to first footnote\footnote{
Fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fillfillfillfi.
} refer to second footnote.\footnote{Another footnote.}


\end{document}
```

That the `\footnoterule` and the whole fisrt footnote moves up by one `\par`?

## Edit

It seems that the issue is related to the macro `\zref@labelbyprops` which itself is related to `\protec@write`. Comment the line containing `\reserved@a` in the definition of `\protected@write` and the issue does not happen:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\makeatletter

\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       %\reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}


\newcounter{footdir@label}
\newtoks\footdir@toks
\newcommand*{\footdir@temp}[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \let#1#2%
    \renewcommand{#2}[1]{%
      \footdir@toks{##1}%
      \footdir@toks\expandafter{%
        \the\expandafter\footdir@toks
        \expandafter
        \zref@labelbyprops{\thefootdir@label}{abspage}%
      }%
      \expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\footdir@toks}%
    }%
  }%
}

\footdir@temp\footdir@ORG@footnotetext\@footnotetext{L}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Refer to first footnote\footnote{
Fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill fill
fill fill fill fillfillfillfi.
} refer to second footnote.\footnote{Another footnote.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should eliminate the line break between the end of the first footnote and its terminating curly brace.

Comment: ...using `%` at the end of the line(s). See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)

Comment: @Micro: Well, this does not happen with standard LaTeX footnotes. If you comment the code, then the issue does not happen.

Comment: @Werner: Are you referring to the first `\footnote` or the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: @user56799: Immediately after the first opening brace `{` of the first `\footnote` and on the line ending before the closing brace `}` of the first `\footnote`. Without the use of `%` these lines add an additional space (sometimes referred to as a spurious space), making the line longer than is really necessary. In your particular case it was long enough to actually add a line-break at the end of the line, causing the visually separated footnotes.

Comment: @Werner: Ok, but comment the code and leave the first `\footnote` as it is, then the issue does not occur.

Comment: @user56799: Sure. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're after exactly. That is, what do you want `\footdir@temp` to do with `#1` and `#2` and why there's not use for `#3`?

Comment: Placing a comment character, `%`, at the end of the line is equivalent to eliminating the line break.

Comment: @Werner: This is a small code of one of my packages. I simply do not understand why this issue happens. I need to understand why this issue occurs. Changing `#3` to `#2` does not make any difference really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TeX typesets a paragraph, it removes space at the end of the last line: see for example *TeX by Topic*:

> After the last element of the paragraph TeX implicitly inserts the equivalent of
>
> ```
> \unskip \penalty10000 \hskip\parfillskip
> ```

With a footnote input such as

```
\footnote{
  Some text.
}
```

the result is that the space TeX adds for the end-of-line is removed before the footnote is set.

In your modified version, you have material after the end of the text. While it doesn't typeset anything in the output, it prevents the `\unskip` removing any trailing spaces. So your paragraph ends

```
<text> <space> <zref-code>
```

When TeX typesets that, if the length of the `<text>` is 'unfortunate' then the material added by `zref` will end up on a new line, which as it doesn't typeset anything is then empty. (Any 'invisible' commands are always tricky!)

Probably the most sensible solution is to add an `\unskip` and probably a `\penalty` to your code, *e.g.*

```
\newcommand*\footdir@aux{\unskip\penalty\@M}
\newcommand*{\footdir@temp}[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{%
    \let#1#2%
    \renewcommand{#2}[1]{%
      \footdir@toks{##1}%
      \footdir@toks\expandafter{%
        \the\expandafter\footdir@toks
        \expandafter\footdir@aux\expandafter
        \zref@labelbyprops\expandafter{\thefootdir@label}{abspage}%
      }%
      \expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\footdir@toks}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

(I've put everything added into one macro to make the `\expandafter` chain a bit easier.)

At a technical level, `\write` operations add a 'whatsit': once these are added to material it's very tricky/impossible to do certain things. (One thing the LaTeX3 team have in experimental form is an approach to dealing with whatsits so they don't get added directly in 'uncontrolled' places for exactly this reason.)

Comment: You don't see the issue if your remove the `\write`  (in your edit) as then there is no whatsit to worry about :-)

Comment: Note of course that each footnote is (with the standard set up) typeset as a paragraph from the TeX point of view.